# Getting error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. after rerendering page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, backend

I am trying to build a registration page with nodeJS and firebase.

When the user gets a registration error the page reloads and the error is shown to the user. 
Then if the user tries to register, he gets to the desired page but I get:

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

After several hours of researching, I think I have understood the problem. 
My code is probably already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried to set a header or statusCode

With this knowledge, I tried to solve this error but I don't get it done.

Here is my user.js(controller) code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var errors;
var errorMessage;

/**
sign up
*/
//sign up page route
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(errors);
  if (errors) {
  //Handle the errors and show them to the user
  res.render('signUp', {error: true, errorMessage: errorMessage});
}else {
  res.render('signUp', {title: 'Sign up', user: false, login: true});
}
});

// sign up request
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){

  console.log(req.body.user.email + ' made a registration request');
  console.log('Passwword: ' + req.body.user.password);

  var email = req.body.user.email;
  var password = req.body.user.password;
  
  //reference to the firebase database 
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error.code);
      console.log(error.message);
      errorMessage = error.message;
      errors = true;
      res.redirect('/');
    } 
  });
  //if user is logged in redirect to homepage
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      res.redirect('/users/home');
      console.log('User: ' + user.email + ' has logged in');
    }
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I think you are trying to redirect twice. first to `/` then to `/users/home` since you don't stop the code from continuing once the first redirect happens.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn thanks for your answer! Do you know how I can stop the code from continuing? something like a break?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 7+ of node, you can use `async/await` like I did in the following snippet:

```js
var express = require('express');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var errors;
var errorMessage;


async function createUser(email, password) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.code);
        console.log(error.message);
        errorMessage = error.message;
        errors = true;
        return resolve(true)
      }
      resolve(false)
    });
  })
}

async function authChange() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        console.log('User: ' + user.email + ' has logged in');
        return resolve(true)
      }
      resolve(false)
    });
  })
}


// sign up request
router.post('/', async function(req, res, next) {

  console.log(req.body.user.email + ' made a registration request');
  console.log('Passwword: ' + req.body.user.password);

  var email = req.body.user.email;
  var password = req.body.user.password;

  //reference to the firebase database 
  let error = await createUser(email, password)
  if (error) {
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    let logged = await authChange()
    if (logged) {
      res.redirect('/users/home');
    }
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am not getting any errors but after logging in it don't redirect to the home site. Any suggestions?